# Laravel seems to be caching errors?

Tags: php, laravel

So I just had an error on laravel.

> Call to a member function getName() on null

I was running this code

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view)
{
    $view->with('route_name', ucfirst(explode(".", \Route::current()->getName())[1]));
});
```

This code only broke in the first place on one of my pages, a newly added route. The pages that it worked on seem to be caching whatever was there before, I even made the second argument "test".

It seems to be caching the error when I've replaced the code? But only showing the error on the page it showed it, to begin with.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not too familiar with composers. But, I do know that Laravel caches **views**, so that may be your problem. Try running `php artisan view:clear` and check if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the case here, the error still exists after.